# Where is meta-inf directory?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, netbeans, meta-inf

I'm working with JPA and Hibernate. Where is meta-inf directory in Netbeans 7.x? For some reazon it seems to not be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a .jar file is produced, this zip file will contain a META-INF directory with maybe a **manifest.mf** in it. In general this can be automatically generated.

In NetBeans the build process either uses **ant** and since a couple of years also **maven** as build engine. In maven one would find generating the manifest.mf (and consequently its directory META-INF) in the **pom.xml**. Try f0r instance setting the main-class of an application jar.

Comment: Thanks for your help, im a newbie in JPA. I have been thought that my problem was in the meta-inf file, because all example uses this file. I try to implement Hibernate over JPA (in respective last versions)  whit JSF. 
Im so sorry if i asked a wrong question, i read a lot of information on internet, and i cant make it work.
Thanks for all..

Comment: Maybe try JPA+eclipseLink first; a bit easier in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is simply missing? META-INF is not required to exist. So you you should simply created it. :)